# Ref Request: Asymptotics of frequency restricted sequences

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics

Given a sequence of $n$ symbols drawn from an alphabet of size $m$, I wish to count the number of sequences that have no more than $k$ occurrences of any symbol.  What is known about the asymptotic behavior of such sequences?  i.e., are there any reasonable upper bounds in terms of the three parameters $n$, $m$ and $k$?  There must be a name for this, but all I can find is the more specific Stockhausen sequence, which has other restrictions.

Comment: A useful summary of the Stockhausen sequences: http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_3/PDF/v3i1r7.pdf

Comment: To make it clear, Stockhausen sequences are a different notion from what is being asked.